# Array.forEach() and closure

Tags: javascript, performance

After I read [an article about JavaScript optimization](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript), I realize there is a need to remove closures in the code to optimize the memory use.

One code pattern of mine is to use `Array.forEach()` as much as possible, even in such situations:

- modify an external object using items in an array

  ```
  function updateSomething(array, toChange) {
    array.forEach(item => {
      toChange[item] = ''; // do something to change the object
    });
  }
  ```
- create nested `Array.forEach()`

  ```
  array1.forEach(item1 => {
    array2.forEach(item2 => {
      doSomething(item1, item2);
    });
  });
  ```

Apparently the callback function used in the `Array.forEach()` creates closures. So am I abusing the `Array.forEach()` in these cases? Should I go back to `for` loop in performance-sensitive projects?

---

**Follow Up**

I have done some experiments on the `for` loop and `Array.forEach()` function with Node v7.6.0. I have no prior experience on performance test. So let me know if I did something wrong.

- `Array.forEach()` accessing external variable

  ```
  // get the baseline of memory usage
  gc();

  let baseline = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Baseline memory usage: ${baseline.heapUsed / 1024 } KB`);

  let data = { test: 0 };

  function test(data) {
    let array1 = new Array(1000000).fill(1);
    array1.forEach((item) => {
      data.test = data.test + item;
    });
  }

  test(data);

  let final = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Final memory usage: ${final.heapUsed / 1024} KB`);
  console.log(`Memory used: ${(final.heapUsed - baseline.heapUsed) / 1024} KB`);
  ```

  Result

  ```
  Baseline memory usage: 2747.671875 KB
  Final memory usage: 11027.34375 KB
  Memory used: 8279.671875 KB
  ```
- `for` loop

  ```
  // get the baseline of memory usage
  gc();

  let baseline = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Baseline memory usage: ${baseline.heapUsed / 1024 } KB`);

  let data = { test: 0 };

  function test(data) {
    let array1 = new Array(1000000).fill(1);
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      data.test = data.test + array1[i];
    }
  }

  test(data);

  let final = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Final memory usage: ${final.heapUsed / 1024} KB`);
  console.log(`Memory used: ${(final.heapUsed - baseline.heapUsed) / 1024} KB`);
  ```

  Result

  ```
  Baseline memory usage: 2747.453125 KB
  Final memory usage: 11031.546875 KB
  Memory used: 8284.09375 KB
  ```
- nested `Array.forEach()`

  ```
  // get the baseline of memory usage
  gc();

  let baseline = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Baseline memory usage: ${baseline.heapUsed / 1024 } KB`);

  let array1 = new Array(1000).fill(1);
  let array2 = new Array(1000).fill(2);

  array1.forEach((item, index) => {
    array2.forEach(item2 => {
      array1[index] = array1[index] = item2;
    })
  });

  let final = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Final memory usage: ${final.heapUsed / 1024} KB`);
  console.log(`Memory used: ${(final.heapUsed - baseline.heapUsed) / 1024} KB`);
  ```

  Result

  ```
  Baseline memory usage: 2748.109375 KB
  Final memory usage: 3368.5859375 KB
  Memory used: 620.4765625 KB
  ```
- nested `for` loop

  ```
  // get the baseline of memory usage
  gc();

  let baseline = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Baseline memory usage: ${baseline.heapUsed / 1024 } KB`);

  let array1 = new Array(1000).fill(1);
  let array2 = new Array(1000).fill(2);

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
      array1[i] = array1[i] + array2[j];
    }
  }

  let final = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log(`Final memory usage: ${final.heapUsed / 1024} KB`);
  console.log(`Memory used: ${(final.heapUsed - baseline.heapUsed) / 1024} KB`);
  ```

  Result

  ```
  Baseline memory usage: 2745.59375 KB
  Final memory usage: 3234.2890625 KB
  Memory used: 488.6953125 KB
  ```

**Conclusion**

The increased memory usage of test #1 and #2 has a difference smaller than 0.1%. So it suggests that the `Array.forEach()` does have the same memory efficiency as the traditional `for` loop, even it is accessing external variables and seems to create closures. The magic is done internally.

Noted that in test #3, the callback function of `array2.forEach()` is initialized 1000 times. This can explain why test #3 uses much more memory than test #4.

Comment: I would recommend profiling your code to find out whether or not it's a real issue.

Comment: `forEach`'s purpose is to iterate over the elements in the array. Since that's what you are doing, it's hardly "abusing" the API. It's also different than a `for` loop because it skips holes. However, it's probably not a performance bottleneck.

Comment: "Should I go back to `for` loop in performance-sensitive projects?" I doubt it will be a significant difference. Only make microoptimizations like this if profiling shows that it is useful.

Comment: @FelixKling *It skips holes*, what do you mean?

Comment: @Kinduser `[1,,,2,3].forEach(x => console.log(x));` logs `1`,`2`,`3`, not `1`, `undefined`, `undefined`, `2`,`3`.

Comment: try using `lodash` library

Comment: @ajaiJothi: Why should they do that? How does that solve their problem?

Comment: JavaScript engines optimise code, so even though an extra closure may seem a performance bottleneck, the parser might choose to not generate real closures unless they are necessary for the correct scoping of variables (which is not needed in the examples you have given, except for the function arguments).

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realize there is a need to remove closures in the code to optimize the memory use.

For memory use, only the closures that you *store* somewhere count. When you get memory problems, you should check whether there are classes with lots of instances which each have their own closure instances. It does not mean that you should avoid closures in general.

> One code pattern of mine is to use `Array.forEach()` as much as possible

Don't. Given that you are using ES6, you should be using `for … of` as much as possible (for imperative loops).

> Apparently the callback function used in the `Array.forEach()` creates closures

Yes, but in the examples you've shown they're not avoidable (cannot be moved out into static functions). And given they last only as long as the `forEach` call and will be garbage-collected immediately after, there's no memory strain either.

However, as the article you linked explains, closures are still costly to create (compared to not creating them at all).

> Should I go back to `for` loop in performance-sensitive projects?

Yes, definitely (at least in *really* performance-sensitive locations - no whole *project* will be). However the reason is not the cost of closures, it is the call overhead of functions in general that `forEach` cannot completely optimise.